# What (permit?/visa?) is required for a non-EU citizen to work REMOTELY for a Czech company (from abroad)?

Tags: working-visas, work-permit, foreign-employment, digital-nomads, czech-republic

I'm a US citizen residing in Finland, where I'm studying for a master's degree. A Czech startup would like to hire me for part-time remote work while I continue residing in Finland, but we are all confused about whether they legally can. Is that possible? If so, would I need a Czech work permit, visa, both, neither, or something else?

The Blue Card application for Czechia [requires a visa application](https://immigration-portal.ec.europa.eu/eu-blue-card/czech-republic_en), and the Czech visa applications in turn [require](https://www.mvcr.cz/mvcren/article/a-visa-for-a-stay-of-over-90-days-long-term.aspx?q=Y2hudW09NA%3D%3D) for example "proof of accommodation", "a document on the purpose of your stay", "a travel document", etc. - everything based on the assumption that you will be living in Czechia. It's the same for [the Employee Card](https://www.mvcr.cz/mvcren/article/employee-card-682810.aspx?q=Y2hudW09Mg%3D%3D). The Blue Card itself is a combined work and residence permit, the latter part of which I don't think I would want, as I wish to maintain my residence in Finland and I don't believe that simultaneous legal residence in multiple EU states is allowed.

Czechia recently introduced a ["Digital Nomad visa"](https://www.mzv.cz/seoul/en/ko/longterm/digitalnomad.html), but this seems to be for people who want to move to Czechia and work abroad remotely, whereas I want to do the opposite and work for a Czech company from abroad.

My Finnish residence permit allows me to work 30 hours/week and I currently work 10 hours/week at a part-time job here in Finland which I'd like to also keep.

Answer (score 1):

Since you'll be working in Finland, you'll need a Finnish work authorization, not Czech. You are allowed to work 30 hours, of which you're already using 10, so you have 20 hours/week left under your existing authorization (based on your facts). That's what you can commit for to the Czech company.

If you're their employee, they may have some liability based on the Finnish labor laws for payroll/social security/etc.

Comment: Thanks. To clarify, you're saying that the Czech company is indeed allowed to hire me as an employee?

Comment: @CaseyJones I have no idea what the Czech company is allowed to do in Finland. But **you** need employment authorization from the country where **you** reside, not your employer.

Comment: Thank you, but I already knew that from my side I must comply with Finnish labor law. My question is whether it is possible for a non-EU national living in another EU state to become an employee of a Czech company, and what is needed to arrange that if so.